# Filter realm results with ANY and AND

Tags: swift, realm, nspredicate

I have this NSPredicate:

```
results?.filter("ANY childs.property = 'prop1' AND ANY childs.key contains[c] %@", "key1")
```

The above code returns all objects that have a child of property 'prop1' or a child of key 'key1'

What I need is to return only the objects that have a child with both property 'prop1' AND key 'key1'

**Detailed Explanation**

I have objects of `Person`s

Each `Person` has a `childs` property which is a list of `Kid`

Each `Kid` has two string properties `prop` and `key`

- `Person[0]` has two Kids in the childs list

  - `Kid[0].prop = prop1` and `Kid[0].key = key1`
  - `Kid[1].prop = prop2` and `Kid[0].key = key2`
- `Person[1]` has two Kids in the childs list

  - `Kid[0].prop = prop1` and `Kid[1].key = key2`
  - `Kid[1].prop = prop2` and `Kid[1].key = key1`

The predicate above returns both Persons, while what I need for it is to return only the first person because only the first person has a child with `prop1` and `key1`

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the ensure that both of the criteria are fulfilled by the same object, you need to use a subquery:

```
results?.filter("SUBQUERY(childs, $child, $child.property = 'prop1' AND $child.key contains[c] %@).@count > 0", "key1")
```